# Connect Java with Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I have created a Java gui and want to execute MATLAB (.m) functions to execute on `click` events of jButtons of my Java GUI. I searched on internet and found a way to do this by MATLAB Builder.

Is there any other way than MATLAB Builder which can be used to perform the same?

Comment: *"Is there any other way than MATLAB Builder?"*  Why do you need another way?  What is wrong with that way?

Comment: Because it makes the project consisting only with .java files and I want Matlab (.m) files included in the project (because of  some reasons)....

Comment: *"because of some reasons"*  Gee, can you vague that up for me?  It is in danger of containing *actual information*.  ***What reasons?***

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [JMI](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/) or [JMatLink](http://jmatlink.sourceforge.net/) to interface with MATLAB from Java.  Or, if you're more adventurous, you can roll your own JNI or JNA library to interface directly with MATLAB's C API.

Answer (score 0):

[matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/) is a Java API which will allow you to call MATLAB from Java. You can either call MATLAB from within MATLAB or from outside MATLAB in which case an instance of MATLAB is launched and connected to. It allows for invoking eval and feval in MATLAB and returning the results to MATLAB. The [walkthrough](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough) explains with examples how to do this.